# exported variables got undefined while functions get exported in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am creating the nodejs application which uses the mongodb.

I am connecting to mongodb only once. I want to use `db` in all other api's so as to achieve the connection pooling.

I have following code for mongodb connectivity:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB";
/**
 * Connects to the MongoDB Database with the provided URL
 */


exports.connect = function(callback){
    if(!db){
        MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, _db){
            if (err) { throw new Error('Could not connect: '+err); }
            db = _db;
            console.log(db);
            connected = true;
            console.log(connected +" is connected?");
            callback(db);
        });     
    }else{
        console.log("Not connected tis time as I am already connected");
        callback(db);
    }

};


exports.db = db;
```

I am calling `connect` only once when server starts from `app.js`. Whenever other api such as `signin, register` get called, they should simply use db that is exported.

So my api calls will something like(please ignore the syntax error in api call :D):

```
var mongo  = require('./mongo');

collection = mongo.db.collection("testCollection");
// Here mongo.db id undefined
collection.findOne({"name":"John"}, function(err, result){
   // Do your stuff with result here
});
```

From other stackoverflow posts, I tried something like in mongo.js as

```
module.export{
db: db,
connect : function(callback){
  //function code goes here
}
}
```

But still I am getting the `undefined` for `mongo.db`
How would I access mongo.db in my other files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is, because connect overwrites `db` in the module. The `exports.db=db;` is not executed after calling your `connect` function, but on execution of the module import.

So, when you call `connect`, db is set to another variable, but that is not exposed outside.

Didn't do much JS lately, but this should do it:

```
module.exports = new mongobj();

function mongobj() {
   this.db = null;
   this.connect = function(callback) { /* your connect code set mongobj.db */
      this.db = /* new value */ ;
   }
}
```

When you import the module, you get the object. Accessing the objects `db` property will always expose the latest `db` value set by the `connect` function of the module.

```
var mongo = require('yourmodule');

// mongo.db is null
mongo.connect(some callback);
// mongo.db is set
```

Comment: then How would I get updated value? Is there is way or it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

This connection add in main script file...

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB";


ObjectId = module.exports = require("mongojs").ObjectId;
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, database){
    if(err){
        console.log("mongodb error >>"+err);    
    } else {
        db = module.exports = database;
    }});


db.collection('game_users').findOne({_id:ObjectId("123456789")},function(err, data) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

define an object:

```
var db = {__db: undefined}
```

and then:

```
exports.db = db
const db = require('./mongo').db.__db
```